# Count frequency of value in columns, then change format of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8

15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15

3   15  15  15  7   15  15  15

15  2   1   15  9   15  15  8

15  15  15  15  15  15  15  1

15  15  1   15  15  15  15  15
```

I want to count frequency of value in each column of data, known that range of value (1:15).
Then, i want to change dataframe with header is (name, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), format likes that:

```
Name    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15

S1  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4

S2  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4

S3  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3

S4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5`
```

Can you help me?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick base R option using `table` + `stack`

```
> t(table(stack(df)))
    values
ind  1 2 3 7 8 9 15
  S1 0 0 1 0 0 0  4
  S2 0 1 0 0 0 0  4
  S3 2 0 0 0 0 0  3
  S4 0 0 0 0 0 0  5
  S5 0 0 0 1 0 1  3
  S6 0 0 0 0 0 0  5
  S7 0 0 0 0 0 0  5
  S8 1 0 0 0 1 0  3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(S1 = c(15L, 3L, 15L, 15L, 15L), S2 = c(15L, 15L, 
2L, 15L, 15L), S3 = c(15L, 15L, 1L, 15L, 1L), S4 = c(15L, 15L,
15L, 15L, 15L), S5 = c(15L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 15L), S6 = c(15L, 15L,
15L, 15L, 15L), S7 = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), S8 = c(15L,
15L, 8L, 1L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

or

```
> t(sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = seq(max(df))))))
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
S1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  4
S2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  4
S3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  3
S4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  5
S5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  3
S6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  5
S7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  5
S8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  3
```

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. What is your technique to get the OP data into R? Did you manually enter the data, or use something like `read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), header=TRUE, row.names = NULL)`?

Comment: Thank you! It worked ^^

Comment: @iamericfletcher See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything())%>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value,
       values_fill = 0, values_fn = length)
```